# Are new objects created in a numpy ND array while slicing?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In numpy if we have a nD array and then we have multiple slices of the same nD array then if we make change in one of them then it's gonna reflect in all slices[i.e. no new object is created] Then why if we check the id() of these slices then they appear different?

Ex::

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])
b = a[:5]
c = a[2:6]
d = a[3:7]
a
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
b
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
c
array([30, 40, 50, 60])
d
array([40, 50, 60, 70])
a[3]=9999
a
array([  10,   20,   30, 9999,   50,   60,   70,   80,   90])
b
array([  10,   20,   30, 9999,   50])
c
array([  30, 9999,   50,   60])
d
array([9999,   50,   60,   70])
id(a)
1592350341040
id(b)
1592350341424
id(c)
1592353526704
id(d)
1592750164944
```

```
                            .
```

Comment: `id` tells you nothing useful about numpy arrays or their slices.  Slices, including single element ones, are new objects, and have their own id.  What you need to understand is when indexing produces a `copy` (advanced indexing) or a `view` (basic indexing).  Both cases are new objects.

Comment: An array has attributes like shape and dtype, and a `data_buffer`.  Your 'slices' share `a's` data.  Thus `b.base` will show `a`.  This `b` is a `view` of `a`.  `id` doesn't tell us anything about the shared base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because slices can also be thought of as "views". They are all *different views* into the same actual *memory* on your computer.

So, if you change the content of that memory via one view, the other views will reflect that change.

However, they *are* different views, and hence they have different results for `id`.